# (MIPS) How can I identify and compare a string stored in a .word

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-word

I am really struggling with the wording of a project I am working on. For mips they are requesting that I take in two arguments before launch. I store both of them into .word memory addresses. However, it then asks me to treat them as though they are .asciiz files and dissect it character by character in a way that spits back only an integer (and if it's value is negative).

> The $a0 register will contain the number of arguments passed to your
>   program. The $a1 register contains the starting address of an array of
>   strings. Each element in the array is an item that you specified on
>   the command line. The labels arg1 and arg2 each store the starting
>   address of a null-terminated sequence of ASCII characters.

My question is how do I properly extract and use the address to get to this sequence of characters they are discussing. Furthermore, where should I store it?

```
.data
     align 2
     arg1: .word 0
     arg2: .word 0
.macro load_args
     lw $t0,0($a1)
     sw $t0, arg1
     lw $t1,4($a1)
     sw $t1, arg2
.end_macro
.text
.globl main
main:
     load_args()
```

Comment: What is the actual wording of your assignment?  Are you storing *pointers* into `.word` locations?  Also, surely it doesn't say "`.asciiz` files", because string constants aren't files.  (They might be file *names*?)  Also, MIPS programming obviously has nothing to do with `[x86]`, don't add unrelated tags.

Comment: Also, your last sentence says "Here is my code", but there's no code.

Comment: Anyway, a string doesn't fit in a `.word` unless the string is at most 4 bytes long (because that's the MIPS word size).  Either your strings are always short, or you're doing it wrong, or you're misreading the assignment.

Comment: When I run the macro load_args (built into MIPS) I do this to set the two words:

Comment: lw $t0,0($a1) sw $t0, arg1
 lw $t1,4($a1)
 sw $t1, arg2

Comment: [edit] your question with your code and the assignment text.  Instead of a messy question + comments, put everything in the question.  See [ask].

Comment: @PeterCordes Okay I altered it. By the way I just wanted to say thank you for trying to help me I really appreciate it. Is this formatting okay? (I am trying my best this is my first time actually posting on here)

Comment: That's better formatting, and paragraphs are much better than a wall of text.  Assuming the middle paragraph is a quote from your assignment, yes, you have *pointers* to strings, so they're addresses, not string data directly.  There's no reason to store those addresses into static `.word` locations; just keep them in registers (and write comments to keep track of what's where).  Adding a bunch of load/store instructions to keep static memory in sync with registers is just a potential source of bugs and more to wade through while debugging.

Comment: Looks like your function is called like `main(int argc, char *argv[])`.  So `$a1` points to an array of words, where each word is a *pointer* to a 0-terminated ASCII string.  At least that's what I assume they mean.  So after `load_args`, `$t0` and `$t1` hold  `argv[0]` and `argv[1]`, and dereferencing *those* (like `lb $t9, ($t0)`) will give you bytes from the strings.